# Can I give my team a private key for an ssh linux repository that limits access?

Tags: linux, private-key, access-control

I have a linux repository in my school that allows me to access my own root. Could I give my team a private key that only allows them to R/W on certain folders in my own directory?

For instance I would have two folders like so: path/to/folder1 & path/to/folder2.

Could I specify a specific private key to only having access to those two folders and nothing else? In any other folder, an attempt to R/W would result in (access denied). They would be logging in as me, but the private key would default to this limited access.

Edit: Even better. All I really want them to be able to do is **git merge main**. That's it. I want them to be able to be inside of my root, and do the command git merge main. Only access I want them to have.

Comment: I think that this might address what I'm looking for: https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8257

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use the `command` parameter in your `authorized_keys` file for that. See AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT in https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sshd.8.html:

> `command="command"`
>
> Specifies that the command is executed whenever this key is
> used for authentication.  The command supplied by the user
> (if any) is ignored. ...
> This option might be useful to restrict certain public keys
> to perform just a specific operation.  An example might be
> a key that permits remote backups but nothing else.